# asp.net VB Need to set default value for Listview or SQL Insert

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, sqldatasource

Hope I can make this clear. I have:

Listview with a sql datasource
a separate dropdown that when something is selected filters the listview/sqldatasoure

What I am trying to do is use the value from the dropdown to also set the default value for the insert record. I see two places either the textbox on the listview iteminsert or the defaultvalue on the sqldatasource Insertparameter.

I've tried a session variable from the dropdown event but if I set the textbox it gets wiped after the listview is refreshed. There doesn't appear to be a way to set the insertparamater on the sqldatasource.

I'm trying to find the right event and property to set. Everything I've tried so far errors out when I reference the textbox directly or use findcontrol with the object or block var not set. In other words the .net hierchary frustrates the heck out of me.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you just update the `DefaultValue` of the insert parameter in your dropdown's `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

---

```
Protected Sub ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

      MySqlDataSource.InsertParameters("ParameterName").DefaultValue = ddl.SelectedValue

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that but an insert error says it's null which I assumed meant since I used the dropdown to also filter the sqldatasource the datasource is being refreshed and wiping out the defaultvalue.

Comment: Applying a filter to the datasource should not modify its insert parameters. If need be, an alternative might be to store the `SelectedValue` of the dropdown in a hiddenfield. When you do the insert, set the Insert Parameter to the value of the hiddenfield.

Comment: That was my first thought but for some reason it's coming through null. I can't use a hidden field because the insert parameter is actually a textbox that can override the default. Which just caused me to think. Isn't the default value there in case the text box is empty? I can also set a session var but I'm having trouble figuring out which event to use to set the defaultvalue or even just that textbox as far as that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Santi,
Thanks for responding, it helped me think through it, you were on the right track. My dropdown stores the value in a session variable then I check the text box on the ListView's ItemInserting and if it's blank set the datasource to the session var. Similar to this

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemInserting
        If txtCategoryInsert.Text = "" Then
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("Category").DefaultValue = Session("CatDefault")
        End If
    End Sub
```